# NSLayoutConstraint Positioning proportionally

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

The parent view (green rectangle) contains many subviews.

Lets consider only for one subview it has horizontal position with x offset from 0.

And whenever the parent view's width is changed lets say with factor of `a`, I need the subview to be positioned  with offset equal to `a * x`

[image]

As much I understood `NSLayoutConstraint` does not allow to set a contraint for red subview's attribute `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` based on containing green views width `NSLayoutAttributeWidth`.

Any suggestion/reference how to acheive proportional positioning like described by means of `NSLayoutConstraint` is welcomed.

Comment: What is your specific use case? Are you wanting to have this spacing change on rotation, or more generally on any size change in the green view?

Comment: The use case is any size change in the green view

Comment: buddy don't do it using manually coding. just make XIB and manage it from Interface Builder. it will decrease you code level also.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to lay it out in Interface Builder but you can use the `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` on the super view in code.

This way you can give it a multiple which will keep the position correct when the superview is updated.

If that doesn't work you can use a "spacer" view.

So you will have them both in the green superview like this...

```
|[spacerView][redView] //using VFL
```

Then you can set the width of the spacer view proportionally to the width of the green view.

Just set the `spacerView` to hidden or give it an alpha of 0.0 so it doesn't show.

Comment: Firstly thanks for the response (+1)! But what I really want is to avoid spacer views, as currently I'm having lots of subviews in containing view, and don't want to have additional spacers. 

Basically what I have for the subviews (reds) are `(originX, originY, width, height)` data. And would like to use `autolayout`ing in order to avoid manual recalculation of coordinates. 

Can you suggest constraint only with existing subviews (no spacers) ?

Comment: Does using the `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` not work if you do it in code?

Comment: No, because `NSLayoutAttributeLeft` cannot be connected to `NSLayoutAttributeWidth` of the parent view.

Comment: @deimus Ah, of course. I think the only way around this is to use spacer views unfortunately. Unless you can use something else completely like a `UICollectionView` with a custom layout.

Comment: @deimus p.s. embrace `IB` if you don't you will soon get left behind. With the updates coming in iOS8 and Xcode 6 Interface Builder will become unavoidable.

Comment: Basically the other solution is to play around with `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` of subview and `NSLayoutAttributeCenterX` of parent view. But in this case I've no idea how to set the sizes of the subviews, as I've to choose either `autolayout`ing or either manual framing of the subviews.

Comment: Hmm... I have had to drop back to `CGRectMake` a couple of times in the past when AutoLayout wouldn't do everything for me. Maybe this is one of those occasions?

Comment: Seems yes, otherwise the available solutions are making the app more complex.

Comment: Exactly, I could have done auto layout in mine but it would have taken more code than just doing manual layout. The good thing is though that you don't need to do it for everything just the view you need to lay manually. Take a look at `UICollectionView` though. You can probably do this with a custom layout.

Comment: I'll check the `UICollectionView` and will be back here, if it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you cannot relate the left attribute of your subview with the width of the superview, but you can relate it to NSLayoutAttributeRight, *which has the same value as the width*. So you should be able to do it by using a multiplier (and 0 for the constant),

```
[_greenView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_redView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:_greenView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight multiplier:.1 constant:0]];
```

Of course you need to do the calculation to figure out, based on the width of the green view, what the multiplier should be. So, in my example, the greenView was 200 points wide to start with, and I wanted the red view to be 20 points from the left, so I used 0.1 for the multiplier.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Due to complex structure of green and red(s) view I had to do the layouting by manual calculation of the frames. In my case this way the code stays more simple. So I decided to skip autolayouting